RabbitMQ IO threads
I was reading .net documentation(https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-seven-dotnet) for the RabbitMq.Client library and reached this part
var channel = connection.CreateModel();
channel.ConfirmSelect();
channel.BasicAcks += (sender, ea) =>
{
  // code when message is confirmed
};
channel.BasicNacks += (sender, ea) =>
{
  //code when message is nack-ed
};

Quote: It can be tempting to re-publish a nack-ed message from the corresponding callback but this should be avoided, as confirm callbacks are dispatched in an I/O thread where channels are not supposed to do operations. A better solution consists in enqueuing the message in an in-memory queue which is polled by a publishing thread. A class like ConcurrentQueue would be a good candidate to transmit messages between the confirm callbacks and a publishing thread.
I read about OS-level IO threads, but i'm pretty sure it's not about them. How can a thread be IO? Why they're tellings me i should't be doing this
channel.BasicNacks += async (sender, ea) =>
{
   var someIoReuslt = await channel.BasicPublishAsync(queue,...);
};

I tried to look at the internal implementation of the Channel, how they're invoking all the callbacks that're subscribed on this event(nack received)
protected void HandleBasicAck(IncomingCommand cmd)
{
    var ack = new BasicAck(cmd.MethodSpan);
    if (!_basicAcksWrapper.IsEmpty)
    {
        var args = new BasicAckEventArgs(ack._deliveryTag, ack._multiple);
        _basicAcksWrapper.Invoke(this, args);
    }

    HandleAckNack(ack._deliveryTag, ack._multiple, false);
}

apart from return type void i see no problem here in terms of performance!

The I/O operations in rabbitmq are mainly for communication between rabbitmq client and rabbit mq broker.
The callbacks ( BasicAcks, BasicNacks ) will use the I/O thread, so you may wonder why this can be a problem. Rabbitmq is designed for fast message transfer and non-blocking message transfer. When you perform heavy operations in the callback, these will happen on the I/O thread that rabbitmq uses, which will affect the performance and may even cause deadlocks ( if you perform heavy tasks in the I/O thread, communication might be interrupted ). Thus, the rabbitmq tutorial suggests using re-queuing strategy like ConcurrentQueue because it provides thread-safe communication between threads. It can hold nacked messages until they are  re-published
For handling this re-publishing, you can create a queue service and consume within this service,
Microsoft official docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/queue-service
Hope it helps,

That's exactly what RabbitMQ docs say but i want to understand it deeper what these IO threads are. How can a thread be IO? Why it's preferable not to use heavy operations?

I/O thread is technical term. Generally used to refer dedicated thread responsible for handling I/O tasks, such as reading data from files, sockets, or networks, or writing to them. In RabbitMq, the I/O thread manages communication between RabbitMq client and the RabbitMq broker. As mentioned above, this communication must be efficient.   Since callbacks ( BasicAcks, BasicNacks ) are executed on the I/O thread, it's important not to place heavy tasks within these callbacks to avoid performance degradation.

I'm sorry but i can't just grasp it like this. It's all to abstract. Could you please write a code where thread could be considered IO and shouldn't be doing long-running tasks or provide a link that refers to a system with implementation based on IO thread? I delved into the RabbitMQ.Client library but didn't find much

https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-dotnet-client/blob/624cf2eab35d04a10a98de8d66409d5d3663ff92/projects/RabbitMQ.Client/client/impl/ChannelBase.cs#L609
Can you please check this, _basicNacksWrapper? Invoke(this, args); when you subscribe to basicNacks ( or BasicAcks ), it will Invoke your implementation and block the whole thread until it completes. That's why you should not do heavy operations in the callback  => channel.BasicNacks += async (sender, ea) =>
{
// Don't do this!! below
var someIoReuslt = await channel.BasicPublishAsync(queue,...);
};

That's probably it! I noted this part myself before but didn't realize how it works. Thank you

glad it helped, thank you
